# How can I ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN to populate the numeric count of the sequential occurrence of a field value within a table?

Tags: mysql, duplicates

How can I ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN to populate the numeric count of the sequential occurrence of a field value within a table?  Lets call the new column 'occurrence'.  In a table, one column/field is 'rec_id'.  Within the table, there can be anywhere from 1 to 1,000 records with the same 'rec_id'.  I assume organizing the 'rec_id' column before running the script would make for a more efficient query.  After running the query, there should be an additional column 'occurrence' that includes the sequential occurrence of each 'rec_id' in the table.  Therefore, the first occurrence of each 'rec_id' would reflect a '1', the second would reflect '2', the third '3',...etc.

Comment: First you have to decide if you are using mysql or sql server. They are not the same thing. Regardless of the DBMS you will need to first add the column, then update it with values. The way you update this depends on which DBMS you are using.

Comment: Using mysql.  I selected sql server by accident.

Comment: Anybody have an idea?

Comment: I found a tutorial on what I want to achieve, but the code is not working for me.. (http://explainextended.com/2009/03/08/analytic-functions-sum-avg-row_number/)

Comment: You have to a little better than "it isn't working". What did you try? Do you get an error message? I can't see your screen so I have no idea what the issue is here.